# First traceroute hop always slow. Why?

Tags: traceroute

Browsers in my LAN, no matter the device, are always slow to connect to internet servers, but after the connection is made webpages download rather fast.

Speedtest.net reports what I would call a rather fast internet connection speed.

Namebench says that my «current primary DNS server is Fastest», and indeed `dig obscuredomain.com` returns a result near instantaneously.

Traceroute (on macOS), though, has the first hop always, infallibly, systematically, timing out returning `* * *`(takes ~10 sec). The second hop displays an IP that is always the same no matter the server I try to connect to or in the same range (I tried now and a few days ago and I can only confirm that first two numbers were the same; they first two numbers are also the same as the ones of my own IP, BTW).

What can the first hop always timing out mean, when it is not due to slow name resolving?

```
$ traceroute -n nausicaa.net
traceroute to nausicaa.net (184.173.122.226), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  213.195.112.1  5.702 ms  5.957 ms  23.590 ms
 3  10.15.3.57  4.932 ms  5.974 ms  6.427 ms
 4  10.15.3.14  5.196 ms  5.508 ms  4.555 ms
 5  213.242.109.89  13.617 ms  13.325 ms  13.633 ms
 6  4.69.206.81  107.324 ms  106.877 ms  106.964 ms
 7  4.16.253.142  107.276 ms  107.191 ms  107.006 ms
 8  169.45.18.176  107.997 ms  118.783 ms  107.929 ms
 9  169.45.18.184  107.667 ms * *
10  * 50.97.17.165  126.468 ms *
11  * 50.97.17.162  138.171 ms *
12  50.97.17.57  140.740 ms  138.974 ms  139.650 ms
13  50.97.18.193  209.981 ms
    173.192.18.215  138.209 ms  139.719 ms
14  173.192.118.139  139.715 ms  139.320 ms
    173.192.118.141  262.584 ms
15  184.173.122.226  137.322 ms  139.245 ms  138.911 ms

$ traceroute -n -I nausicaa.net
traceroute to nausicaa.net (184.173.122.226), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  213.195.112.1  6.703 ms  5.925 ms  4.782 ms
 3  10.15.3.57  4.776 ms  5.826 ms  5.343 ms
 4  10.15.3.14  5.395 ms  6.958 ms  5.077 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * 4.69.206.81  105.994 ms
 7  4.16.253.142  106.591 ms  106.862 ms  115.811 ms
 8  169.45.18.176  110.287 ms  211.797 ms  108.709 ms
 9  169.45.18.184  109.032 ms *  109.376 ms
10  * * 50.97.17.165  126.383 ms
11  * * *
12  50.97.17.57  140.749 ms  138.998 ms  138.941 ms
13  173.192.18.215  250.969 ms  139.695 ms  146.931 ms
14  173.192.118.139  140.894 ms  186.317 ms  139.711 ms
15  184.173.122.226  140.457 ms  139.831 ms  140.058 ms

$ traceroute -n google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.214.174), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  213.195.112.1  6.754 ms  10.904 ms  5.777 ms
 3  10.15.3.57  5.427 ms  5.135 ms  4.817 ms
 4  10.15.3.14  5.086 ms  4.932 ms  4.806 ms
 5  * * *
 6  4.68.111.46  14.354 ms  15.889 ms  19.699 ms
 7  74.125.242.161  14.783 ms
    74.125.242.177  16.940 ms
    74.125.242.161  15.619 ms
 8  172.253.50.73  14.632 ms  13.989 ms
    172.253.50.75  13.863 ms
 9  216.58.214.174  13.606 ms  13.634 ms  14.182 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first hop isn't timing out, it's just not responding to your traceroute ICMP probe. This first hop device (which is your Default Gateway) may be configured to block/discard/ignore ICMP traffic destined to it.
2. If the MAC address of the Default Gateway ip address is not in your host cache then there will naturally be a delay of some interval (probably in the millisecond range) while your host does an ARP for the MAC address of the Default Gateway ip address.